# function inside function is not working in django

Tags: python, django

i have written a function inside a function for getting image height and width.
but when i hit url all code works except get_image_size function
this is my code

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    """
    Modified Context Data in PDP pages
    """
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        urlImage = 'http://'+ str(self.request.get_host()) + '/media/images/products/2016/12/dog.jpg'
        print "link is",urlImage


        def get_image_size(urlImage):
            print "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,,"
            data = requests.get(urlImage).content
            im = Image.open(BytesIO(data))    
            return im.size


        if __name__ == "__main__":
            print "===========>"
            width, height = get_image_size(urlImage)
            print "height is--", height
            print "width is --",width
```

what is the issue with it.

Comment: Probably that your function is local to get_context_data. You can't access it from outside. What's the traceback ? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: no i am not getting any error. just not getting this function working.outer def is working proporly.

Comment: Do you see any of your print ?

Comment: It should be `data = self.requests.get(urlImage).content`.

Comment: @yorodm no this is not working

Comment: @iFlo no i dont see any print

Comment: @yorodm - `requests` is the python library, not the django variable (and if it were the django variable `request.GET.get` would be what you'd need).

Comment: So the function was not your issue. Think more globally to find where the issue come from. If you don't see the print, that means that you don't even passed the `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django views is not executed as main program. If you print `__name__` you'll see something like `app_name.views`and not `__main__`

Try to remove `if __name__ == "__main__":` validation.